# Entity framework - having the same table in more than one edmx

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two edmx files .
Both contain the table "applicationType".
That means I have two objects applicationType with different namespace.
When I try to query from one
I get the following error -

```
 "Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nMultiple types with the name 
 'ApplicationType' exist in the EdmItemCollection in different namespaces.  
  Convention based mapping requires unique names without regard to namespace 
  in the EdmItemCollection.\r\nThe relationship   
  'myModel.FK_ApplicationAttribute_ApplicationType' was not loaded because the type 
  'myModel.ApplicationType' is not available.\r\n"} 
   System.Data.EntityException {System.Data.MetadataException}
```

can anyone suggest how to query it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the two Models are in the same namespace, you must have different names for these objects. Eg:

Model 1 - namespace: myApp - table: applicationType - entityName: applicationType

In your second model you must use another namespace, or, another entityName.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open one of yours edmx diagrams
2. right click at the replicated entity and rename it
3. Save it, build the project
4. Adjust errors that possible will appear with code that uses the entity you just rename (only update entity name).